# LINUX - Is ubuntu a good platform to learn LINUX?

Tags: linux

Some new opening IT positions require solid LINUX or UNIX knowledge. I would like to know whether or not ubuntu is a good platform to start to learn such skills.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, but StackOverflow is not a good platform to post this question.

Comment: not programming related, try SuperUser; and I believe this question will be a duplicate over there

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is. As pretty much every other Linux distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it IS Linux, but I'd say it's not ideal for what you want. It's different in some aspects from most other Linux distributions.

If you want to learn Linux for real, I recommend Gentoo. You'll have to do everything by hand, and get familiar with every configuration file and tool there is. You'll have no choice but to learn.

It's a slow process, but if you're eager to learn, you'll enjoy it. That's how I learned!

Hope it helps.

**Edit**: if you have absolutely no knowledge of Linux, or operating systems in general, the learning curve may get too steep. Maybe you could start elsewhere, like an Ubuntu command-line installation, get familiar with that, and then move on to Gentoo.

Comment: "You'll have no choice but to learn." Or give up...

Comment: It's a matter of determination. When I want to learn something, I don't give up.

Comment: I would second the suggestion to use Gentoo.  You may have to do everything by hand but their documentation is excellent.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu should be easy to approach. If you never used any unix-like OS before, go for it. To get more help from the community, see also:

- https://askubuntu.com/
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu is an excellent platform to gain Linux/UNIX knowledge and offers both client and server versions - one based on KDE and one based on GNOME. It is an excellent starting point with much support, documentation, and even books. It is also very easy to install and get up and running.